# Jstree not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony1, jstree

i did a descendant tree for an entity in my app, using the libray [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/). I do what is usual to use it:

- show an `<ul>` & `<li>` structure as usual
- then i apply the `.jstree(...)` function to the parent `<div>` of the structure.

I'm sorry but i can't provide you my source code because is dynamically generated from diferent parts of the app, but i can show a result example of the `<ul>`&`<li>` structure:

```
<div id="unidadtree">
<ul>
    <li id=182 ><a href="-censored-">Node-name</a></li>
    <li id=170 ><a href="-censored-">Node2-name</a>
        <ul>
            <li id=179 ><a href="-censored-">Node2.1-name</a></li>
            <li id=171 ><a href="-censored-">Node2.2-name</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id=172 ><a href="-consored-">Node2.2.1-name</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id=176 ><a href="-censored-">Node2.3-name</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id=178 ><a href="-censored-">Node2.3.1-name</a></li>
                    <li id=177 ><a href="-censored-">Node2.3.2-name</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id=175 ><a href="-censored-">Node2.4-name</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id=33 ><a href="-censored-">Node2.4.1-name</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li id=137 ><a href="-censored-">Node2.4.1.1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

then the js function converting that list into a jstree is:

`

```
$("#unidadtree").jstree({
    "themes" : {
        "theme" : "custom",
        "dots" : false,
        "icons" : true,
    }
});`
```

The problem is that, few times (about 1 of each 50 times) the javascript function seems to not load properly. The result that i see is a normal html `<ul>` & `<li>` structue. The really strange issue is the low frequency of the error. Could be not my fault? Is someone else having this problem?

thank you very much for your time! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because your ID attributes are invalid. In HTML, you should not have all-numeric values for ID. See this post: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Also, the ID's should be surrounded by quotes within the source.

I have experienced cases where all-numeric ID's like you have, have led to unexpected results in some browsers.

Comment: well, i changed it and it seems to work fine, but i can't be sure the problem will not appear again >_<. If in a week everything goes fine i'll assume it as solved. Thank you very much